# Is it bad to have Vertices/Edges/Faces just lying on top of the mesh and not actually be connected

Tags: modeling

Is it bad to have faces just lying on top of the mesh (marked with blue) or is it better to connect them by cutting the mesh under it with knife tool and create 4gon  faces but get more geometry as I did with red ones(marked in red). This is supossed to be game-ready object so it's better to have less faces, on the other hand, this blue marked bars are just lying on top of mesh, and I wonder is that bad for GameReady object.[image]
[image]

Comment: It depends on what you're doing, but generally blender prefers quad based topology when making its calculations. Having extra vertices just sitting" along an edge will cause the connected face to have more than 4 vertices, and thus will be constituted as an n-gon. If you only plan to use flat shading, and there is no need for the mesh to be "manifold" or "watertight", you may get away with it just fine, however, it's best practice to use quads whenever possible as issues will eventually arise with frequent use of n-gon's (particularly with lighting/shading).

Comment: Not actually know what is Manifold or watertight but gonna explore that. I see I would need to do this, because Bevel modifier doesn't work on those n-gons. Any recommendation how to do it fast way, or I need to knife every one by one? Thanks!